# Declaring a UserForm listbox as a variable in a module? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

Alright this is my first post on here so be gentle.

I have a Userform with a listbox containing x amount of values. I have a separate module that calls this Userform and then performs some procedures based on the values chosen in the listbox. I have the following:

```
Dim lb as ListBox

lb = Userform1.Listbox1
For x = 0 to lb.ListCount - 1 Then
    'Do the stuff I need it to
Next x
```

The problem I am getting is that lb returns a "Nothing".

I am sure this is something simple but I can't figure it out. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The userform1.listbox1 is only populated as long as the userform is open, declare a public variable, then set the variable to the listbox, inside the userform module, after the userform is closed you should have the variable available in the procedure from which the userform was called.

Comment: This approach works just as good as the other way (I actually use it for another part of the code), but I ended up just doing everything I needed to while the userform was still "active" with application.screenupdating = false until I exit the original sub procedure

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing your userform before you are running your code, as if this the case then your listbox is effectively non existent in memory and you listcount will not return anything. You can also remove the line where you are assigning your lb variable and directly get the listcount of the listbox like the code below. Also if you dont want the userform to show when you code is doing the loop just hide the userform run the loop and then unload the userform after that. This way you list box is still in memory long enough for the loop to get the correct value

```
for x = 1 to userform.listbox.listcount
    '' Do you stuff
next x
```

I tried the code and it gave me the correct value. If there is anything else let me know and hope this helps :)

Comment: GBSingh, I ended up coding all the necessary things inside the userform module and then dealing with any external things outside of it after I unloaded the userform. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Declare the module just like that.

```
Sub listboxpopulate(listb as string,usf as userform)
for i=0 Usf.controls(listb).listcount-1

Do ur stuff
Next

End sub
```

This will help